# Go through tar archive in memory to extract metadata?

Tags: python, zip, tar

I have several tar archives that I need to extract/read in memory. The problem is each tar contains many ZIP archives and each contain unique XML documents.

So the structure of each tar is as follows: tar -> directories-> ZIPs->XML.

Obviously I can manually extract a single TAR but I have about 1000 TAR archives that are about 3 GB each and contains about 6000 ZIP archives each. I'm looking for a way to handle the .tar archives in memory and extract the XML data of each ZIP.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be doable, since all of the relevant methods have non-disk-related options.

Lots of loops here, so let's dig in.

For each tar archive:

- `tarfile.open` would open the tar archive. ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open))
- Call `.getmembers` on the resulting `TarFile` instance to get a list of the zips (or other files) contained in the archive. ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getmembers))

For each zip within the tar archive:

- Once you know what member file (i.e., one of your zips) you want to look through, call `.extractfile` on your `TarFile` instance to get a file object for that zip. ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile))
- Instantiate a new `zipfile.ZipFile` with your file object in order to open the zip so you can work with it. ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile))
- Call `.infolist` on your `ZipFile` instance to get a list of the files it contains (including your XML files). ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist))

For each XML file within the zip:

- Call `.open` on your `ZipFile` instance in order to get a file object of one of your XML files. ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open))
- You now have a file object corresponding to one of your XML files. Do whatever you want with it: `.read` it, copy it to disk somewhere, stick it in an `ElementTree` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse)), etc.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm brand new to python and just needed some direction.  The overall process seemed fairly straightforward enough, just a lot of looping and digging.  Thanks for the helpful links!

Comment: Yeah of course; sorry this my first question and I wasn't sure really what I was doing